# Only print the lowercase characters in a string

Tags: python, string

How can I write the code so `python` ONLY prints out the **lower case** letters of the string. In this case, it should exclude the P.

I tried this:

```
word = "Programming is fun!"

for letter in word:
        if letter.lower():
        print letter
```

But it doesn't solely print out the lowercase letters. How could I only get the lower-case characters out of the string instead of the whole string in lower-case.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is an almost completely useless bug report.  You can get away with it in a question this simple, because what's wrong is immediately obvious to most experienced Python programmers.  As your programs (and your questions about them) become more advanced, they will require _much_ more information about what you tried, what happened, why you felt that was an error, and what you'd expected to happen instead.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep that in mind. I just started out so i'm not the keenest on talking like a programmer yet.

Answer (score 3):

You want [`letter.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) (which tests), not `letter.lower()` (which converts).

If you want to print non-cased characters too, you'd check:

```
if letter.islower() or not letter.isalpha():
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `islower` instead :

```
letter.islower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours doesn't work because you've called `.lower()`, which is a method of the String class - it changes the case of the letter in question, and results in `True`.

There are likely many ways to obtain the result you want, the simplest I can think of being:

```
word = "Hello World!"
for letter in word:
    if letter.islower():
        print(letter)
```

Note that there is an equality test in mine, which is what yours is missing.

EDIT: As other answers pointed out, `.islower()` is a more succinct way of checking the case of the letter.  Similarly, `.isupper()` would `print` only the capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
print filter(lambda c: c.islower(), word)
```

Answer (score 0):

What will actually answer to your question (as i can tell from provided output) will be something like: 
`import string
 word="Programming is fun!"
 filter(lambda c: c.islower() or not(c.isupper() and c in string.printable), word)`